# Portable opcode generation

Tags: python, jit, portability, opcode

I'm currently developing, in Python, a very simple, stack-oriented programming language intended to introduce complete novices to programming concepts.  The language does allow users to craft their own functions.  While speed isn't a big concern for my language, I thought of creating a "simple" JIT compiler to generate Python byte code for the user's functions.

I was listening to an excellent talk from PyCon on how to hand-craft byte code and make functions from them.  However, the speakers did add a caveat that the specific byte values of Python byte code are in no way portable and can even change between, say, 3.5.1 and 3.5.2.

So, I brought up the documentation for the `dis` module and saw `dis.opmap`, described as

> Dictionary mapping operation names to bytecodes.

Therefore, if I wanted to put a `BINARY_ADD` into a byte code object, I wouldn't need to know its specific value.  I could just look it up in `dis.opmap`.

This finally brings me to my question: Are there any other portability pitfalls of which I need to be aware (e.g., Endianness, sizes/numbers of arguments per opcode) in order to make my JIT compiler compatible with any version of Python 3?  I imagine that there will be certain opcodes that were only made available in a specific version.  However, as I mentally work out my JIT compiler, I can't see myself using anything but the most basic instructions.

Comment: Perhaps but I'm intending this as a gift for my daughter.  She's only 11 weeks now but I'd like to make her first language myself.

Comment: I have no experience with Python 3.x bytecode, but between various 2.x versions there were some *major* changes in how flow control opcodes worked - for example, whether conditional jump opcodes left their operand on the stack.  Looking up values in `dis.opmap` is of limited help when a version change requires you to use an entirely different operation, in a different way!  I think you may find it easier to do code generation by producing Python source, and calling `exec()` on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am fairly certain that Python bytecode is undocumented. It's a messy place and it's a scary place. I'll offer an alternative at the end, but first.... why is it scary? First of all Python is interpreted to bytecode and that bytecode gets ran on a virtual machine. That virtual machine is definitely undocumented. You can take a look [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/commits/main/Python/opcode_targets.h) at the opcode commit history. Notice that it changes... a lot. Beyond that you also have things like f-strings getting implemented which means the underlying C code is going to change. It's a very messy place because so many people are changing it.

Now, here is where my suggestion comes in. The reason that stuff is complicated is because many people are changing it. You daughter is 11 weeks, she ain't gonna be programming for at least another 3 weeks ;). So instead, why not make your own language? I recommend reading https://craftinginterpreters.com/contents.html. It's completely free and walks you through making an interpreted language in Java using AST followed by how to make a virtual machine with byte code and various chunk operations (just like Python has). It's a very easy to read book with good, thought-provoking questions at the end of chapters. You could make a completely customizable language that you ultimately control. Want to change an op code? Go for it. Want all users to be on the same playing field and guarantee backwards compatibility? It's your programming language, do whatever you want.

At the end of the day this is something that is going to be fun for you. And if you have to worry about opcodes being added or changed or overloaded, you're probably not going to be having fun. And when something eventually goes wrong you're going to have to debug your interpreted language, your JIT compiler and Python's source. That's just a headache in the making.

Comment: So, it's not just the opcode values themselves that are changing?

Comment: Correct. Take a look at this rats nest of a [commit history](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/fee552669f21ca294f57fe0df826945edc779090#diff-fd7b118a01a9695dfa16eea9381d3c7b0652e1b7b55f51ff052a1f620d175642). Take a look specifically at the `test_dis.py` stuff being changed. Some become jump targets, some get different op codes, etc. The point is because the language is always maturing, it's always changing. So if people can make opcode level improvements they will.

Comment: And if you're curious how the bytecode get's compiled, take a look at [compile.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/compile.c). Things change there all the time, whether for optimization or PEP reasons or something else entirely.

Comment: Thank you the recommendation!  This book is awesome!